# Understanding glmer algorithm; help with debugging using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate some subset of lme4 in Haskell.  I've managed the `lmer` part, more or less, with results that match the examples in the Bates (2009) "Linear mixed model implementation in lme4" paper. So now I'm onto the generalized bit.
One thing that is slightly reassuring is that I can run my glmer-equivalent on the lmer examples, using a Gaussian family and an identity link function.  So things are not *wildly* wrong.
But when I try to match the cbpp example, even a much simplified version where I just try to match

```
example <- glmer(incidence/size ~ 1 + (1 | herd), data = cbpp,
                 family = binomial(), weights = size)
```

Things don't work. By which I mean that my Haskell version (https://github.com/adamConnerSax/glm-haskell/blob/GLMMs/test/glm/GLMM-test.hs) does not converge to the same answer.

Two things would be a great help:

1. Is there a better reference for the glmer algorithm than the various Bates papers (2007, 2009, 2018)?  Those all have lots of specifics on the LMM piece but a lot less on the GLMM bit.
2. Suppose I have run the above code with the result in `example`.  In lme4, is there a way to just get the value of the various deviance functions at given `beta` and `u` rather than the solution? Can I just run the iteratively-reweighted-least-squares for a fixed value of `theta`, rather than running the whole optimization loop?  The more points of comparison I have between the R and my Haskell code, the easier it'll be for me to see where I went wrong.

Comment: I edited this to significantly narrow it's scope.  Sorry for being too broad!  Can it be un-held? Thanks!

Comment: "Things don't work" is almost useless as a description of your problem--and it isn't necessarily true, because your example can be reproduced and it works fine.  If you can provide a *reproducible* example of the problem you face, this likely would fit well on [SO].

Comment: Okay! Tried again.  
I asked in this forum because I think the people who understand how glmer works are most likely to be able to help.  But then you wanted me to narrow the question. The most important part is the R debugging and I can see how what's left might be a better fit for stackoverflow.  
I'm aware that "Things don't work" is not particularly informative. I'm now linking to my non-working Haskell code in case anyone wants to reproduce my issue. But what I am hoping for is more info about the algorithm and some hints about how to get intermediate results in R for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get an unfinished draft paper on the detailed theory and implementation of GLMMs with the `lme4` package [on r-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/www/JSS/glmer.pdf?root=lme4&view=log) (most `lme4` development has moved from r-forge to GitHub, but the draft of this paper is still here)
2. You can absolutely get the deviance function alone.  The easiest way is probably to take a fitted model and run `update(fitted_model, devFunOnly=TRUE)` (or you can take the same set of arguments and add `devFunOnly=TRUE` in the first place).  There are a few potential tricky bits about whether the first (`nAGQ=0`) or second pass (with `nAGQ>0`) is being run; see `?modular`.

   However, this deviance function might not be quite what you want, since it takes `beta` and `theta` -- but not `u` -- as input. Within the deviance function, the `pwrssUpdate` function runs the PIRLS algorithm.  But this will at least get you closer ... you can look at the source code, or if you have stored a deviance function `devfun`, you can look at `environment(devfun)$pwrssUpdate`

Comment: Thanks!! That pdf will be very helpful, as will more direct ways to see the value of devFun. I’ve looked at the code a bunch but I don’t know R and the C++ is sometimes hard to follow. I think I spotted that first/second pass thing but I’ve got no idea what that is. Is the first iteration for any theta done with a different integral approximation?